# Is the 1D wave equation analytically solvable for a Neumann BC?

Tags: pde

The general solution to the 2nd order wave equation:

$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} = c^2\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$

is known as d'alembert's formula->https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula

Does an analytical particular solution exist for a problem with a Neumann BC on one end, and dirichlet on the other? I am unable to find a solution. I have only been able to find solutions for pure dirichlet BCs.

Comment: This is for a finite domain? Consider what symmetry tells you will happen in the middle if you have a domain twice as long, with the same Dirichlet condition at each end.

Comment: Yes it is for a finite domain. It is a 1D problem in the x-direction, and the dimension is finite. I don't understand your latter comment as it relates to the question (neumann on one end and dirichlet on the other)?

Comment: I was intending to point you towards one way of getting from your solved problem (solution for Dirichlet BCs) to a solution with a Neumann condition. Admittedly a zero Neumann condition, but the extension to non-zero isn't much extra work.

Comment: Ah, so an analytical solution does exist?

Comment: Yes, and unsurprisingly it consists of cosines and sines, plus possibly a linear term.

Comment: http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/fall03/m4354_f03/wave_eq_Neumann_ex.pdf  Essentially something like this? Although this one is derived for Neumann BCs at both ends.

Comment: Hmmm it seems I cannot use separation of variables for my problem. My Neumann BC is NON-zero.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure math question that has already been cross-posted at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. There are lots of ways you can analytically solve this equation.

For instance, you can solve this problem by [Discrete Fourier Transform.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT)

> For Dirichlet BC on both sides: we use {$sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}$} as eigenfunction
>   For Neumann BC: we use {$cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}$}  as eigenfunction
>   And when we have for one side Dirichlet and for the other Neumann we may use either {$sin\frac{(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi x}{L}$} or {$cos\frac{(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi x}{L}$} depending on the side of each BC's type, as eigenfunction.

For the problem you asked, it can be solved with the third type eigenfunction.

You may derive these eigenfunctions from Sturm–Liouville theory.
Please let me know if this was the thing you were looking at.

Comment: If a computational context is required then It still requires proof that the corresponding series would be convergent.